# How to select all same type structures in entire map?

Tags: starcraft-2

I was wondering if it is possible to instantly select all same type structures in entire map (not in territory you are currently watching)?

For example: I want to reallocate multiple spine crawlers scattered around map to front line. So, if there are any, what hotkeys should I use to instantly select them all??
(I also could do that by manually finding them all and sending them elsewhere, but it would be waste of precious time and there would be chance that I might miss few of them.)

p.s. I'm playing HotS

Comment: Control+Shift+Click is the best way you've got. Do so on each area of Spine Crawlers you have and then hotkey them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**It is not possible to select all buildings or units not visible on the screen.**

A tip could be to have all produced Spine Crawlers bound to one shortcut key.
When you make a new Spine Crawler, simply select the group already bound, and hold "Shift" and then click on the new Spine Crawler.
Doing this will make it possible for you to select all Spine Crawler. (at least the ones you grouped).

Comment: Shift-clicking as you describe will only add the new spine to the current selection, not add it to the group.

Comment: You will of cause have to "regroup" with the new selection yes...

Comment: Another way is to just select the new spine and then use the "add to group" hotkey (default shift-#). A little more efficient since you don't have to select the existing group unless you want to use it after.

Comment: Nice one NReilngh

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to select any units (including buildings) of any categorization, that are not on the screen, unless you already have a keybinding for them.